# (click) event not working if I use property binding

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working with Ionic 4 project and I have problem. My Click it not working if I use property binding in the same page.

I tried to do it excluding property binding from page and it worked, but I need both of them

pageName.page.ts function looks like this:

```
 myFunc(){
    alert('hey');
  }
```

pageName.page.html looks like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>matchingGame</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <div>
      <h3 padding>Choose correct Latvian translation for word: <i>{{correctWord.wordENG}}</i></h3>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="myFunc()">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="add"></ion-icon>
        Click me
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="myFunc()">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="add"></ion-icon>
        Click me
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="myFunc()">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="add"></ion-icon>
        Click me
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

So if I take out {{correctWord.wordENG}} , then (click)="myFunc()" works fine, if I don't it also doesn't

Whole page.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DatabaseService } from "../services/database.service";
import { Word } from "../word.module";

@Component({
  selector: "app-matching-game",
  templateUrl: "./matching-game.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./matching-game.page.scss"]
})
export class MatchingGamePage  {
  wordType;
  words: Word[];
  word1: Word;
  word2;
  word3;
  word4;
  found;
  correctWord: Word;
  public displayWords: Word[] = [];

  constructor(private db: DatabaseService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.wordType = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    this.db.getDatabaseState().subscribe(ready => {
      if (ready) {
        this.db.loadWordsByTypeID(2).subscribe(words => {
          this.words = words;
          let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.words.length-1)) + 0;
          this.correctWord = this.words[random];
          this.words.splice(random,1);
          random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.words.length-1)) + 0;
          this.word1 = this.words[random];
          this.words.splice(random,1);
          random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.words.length-1)) + 0;
          this.word2 = this.words[random];
          this.words.splice(random,1);
          random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.words.length-1)) + 0;
          this.word3 = this.words[random];
          this.displayWords[0] = this.correctWord;
          this.displayWords[1] = this.word1;
          this.displayWords[2] = this.word2;
          this.displayWords[3] = this.word3;
          this.shuffle(this.displayWords);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  public myFunc(){
    window.alert('hey');
  }

  shuffle(array) {
    array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  }

  onAnswering(){
   alert('hello');
  }

  displayWord(word: Word, language: string){
    if(language=="LV"){
      return word.wordLV;
    }
    else{
      return word.wordENG;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you get any error in yours developer console?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for this?

Comment: @RuslansSmolonskis so after inspecting your app I found the problem... BUT its nowhere near where you claimed it to be... Soo you either just don't know how to use remote debugging in which case, my apologies, please look here https://ionic.zone/debug/remote-debug-your-app ... OR you just didn't bother with it and hoped someone else will fix your code for you! (See updated answer for solution)

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that your problem is the initial value of `correctWord`.
When you create your component its `undefined` so `correctWord.wordENG` will result in a template error (which you should see in your developer console...)

`this.db.loadWordsByTypeID(2)` will take some time until it finishes so you need to eitner put an `*ngIf` somewhere in your template to delay the component rendering until you got your data:

```
<h3 padding *ngIf="correctWord">Choose ...<i>{{correctWord.wordENG}}</i></h3>
```

or use a valid initial value for `correctWord`:

Try replacing `correctWord: Word;` with `correctWord: Word = {};`

---

**Update:** The actual problem is that `loadWordsByTypeID(...).subscribe((words) => ...)` returns `[]` as first value because you initialized `wordsByTypeID` with `BehaviorSubject([])` in `database.service.ts` ... and the matching-game code you posted can't deal with an empty words array as input.

So either use `wordsByTypeID = new Subject<Word[]>();` in `database.service.ts` or modify your matching-game code so that it can handle `loadWordsByTypeID(...).subscribe((words) => ...)` responding with an empty words array.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I need to delay the component . But how to do that? Tried to to declare variable isShowing = false and at the end of ngOnInit  I set it to true, then content never loaded. Also tried setTimeout(()=>this.showContent=true, 10000); then content showed up, but the components didn't.... Please help

Comment: @RuslansSmolonskis Did you try just using a valid initial value (like correctWord: Word = {}) instead of delaying? Please post all relevant information, you are talking  about new variables like everyone will know what you mean, sure I can guess what they are supposed to do but clearly they aren't working like you expected so how are we supposed to help? As far as I know you just declared some variables with these names and hoped it would magically change things...

Comment: Yes I did it like that - correctWord = new Word(99999, 'ss', 'ss', 1); when I enter the page first time it shows me 'ss', when I leave the page and enter the page again it shows me my expected value from SQL database. Ahh I also added ionViewWillEnter() method which do pretty much the same thing

Comment: @RuslansSmolonskis you can also try to only render the headline after the word is loaded: `<h3 padding *ngIf="correctWord">Choose correct Latvian translation for word: <i>{{correctWord.wordENG}}</i></h3>`

Comment: It's also not working. When I enter the page for first time, it shows blank page. But when I leave page and enter the page again it's working great. Could you please look to my code if I send you my files??